# R dplyr transform column data with calculation that includes column index

Tags: r, lapply, dplyr

I'm trying to transform the data in columns of a dataframe by a calculation that includes the index of the column being transformed.  I have functional code that accomplishes this with a loop through the columns, however, if possible, I'd like to perform this as a dplyr step as there are several other transformations applied to this data as well.

Here's sample code of the behavior:

```
df <- data.frame(column1 = c(1,2,3),column2 = c(1,2,3), column3=c(1,2,3))

for(name in names(df)){
  index <- which(names(df)==name)
  df[name] <- lapply(df[name],function(x) (x+(0.005*index)))
}

df
```

Output:

```
  column1 column2 column3
1   1.005    1.01   1.015
2   2.005    2.01   2.015
3   3.005    3.01   3.015
```

Where I'm struggling converting this to a dplyr step is accessing the column index as part of the transformation.  See the following code  (where df is the same dataframe as above and column_index is a placeholder for some logic):

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("column")),funs(.+(0.005*column_index)))
```

Please advise on the correct way to accomplish this as part of a dplyr step or if it's not possible, a better way to solve this than a loop.

Comment: Please include the expected output too.

Comment: Expected output is now included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a loop approach is cleanest. I would simplify your loop like this:

```
for(col in seq_along(df)){
  df[, col] <- df[, col] + (0.005 * col)
}
```

No `lapply` is needed because `+` is vectorized. And since you care about the column index, not the column name, looping over the column index makes sense.

---

I don't think you'll be able to find a *nicer* way to do this with `dplyr`/`tidyr`. The "tidy" approach would convert your data to a long format, create a `former_column_index` column, and then the calculation would be an  operation on two columns, `mutate(value = value + 0.005 * former_column_index)`. You could, of course, then convert the data back to wide format. This will be much less efficient than the loop approach above.

I'll leave it to anyone else who wants to demonstrate a solution along those lines.

Without more detail about your "several other transformations", hard to judge whether it would help with those.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a `tidyverse` possibility, however, this type of tasks could be achieved more elegantly/efficiently with `base R`:

```
sweep(df, 2, FUN = function(x, y) x + (0.005 * y), seq_along(df))

  column1 column2 column3
1   1.005    1.01   1.015
2   2.005    2.01   2.015
3   3.005    3.01   3.015
```

And you can, of course, use the pipeline for potential further steps:

```
sweep(df, 2, FUN = function(x, y) x +(0.005 * y), seq_along(df)) %>%
 mutate_all(~ . * 10)
```